# Creating an API client that's unit testable

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I'm currently building a simple API client that will provide a nice wrapper around a remote service's HTTP API. I'm having trouble working out how to mock HTTP responses inside my client, in order to make it easily testable.

For example, take the following example class:

```
<?php

class ApiClient
{
    const API_BASEURL = 'https://api.someservice.com/v1';

    protected $applicationId;
    protected $secretKey;

    public function __construct($applicationId, $secretKey)
    {
        $this->applicationId = $applicationId;
        $this->secretKey = $secretKey;
    }

    public function listAccounts()
    {
        $response = \Httpful\Request::get(self::API_BASEURL.'/accounts')
            ->expectsJson()
            ->send();

        return $response->accounts;
    }
}
```

I want the developers that are using my client to be able to use it like:

```
$client = new ApiClient($applicationId, $secretKey);
$accounts = $client->listAccounts();
```

In practice, this works just fine. But it's really hard for me to unit test the `listAccounts()` method, because it sends a HTTP request to a hard-coded `API_BASEURL`. Obviously I don't want my tests to actually fire network calls to a remote service.

I suppose one way around this is to mock the `\Httpful\Request` class, to make it return a "faked" response instead of actually hitting the network. But how do I pass that mocked class into my `listAccounts()` method? I can't change its signature to be `listAccounts($mockedRequest = null)` just for the sake of testing.

What's the best way for me to go about testing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you whould inject the request object into the class (pass it via constructor argument) and remove the hard dependency. But in your case, there is no request object to begin with that you can replace with a mock. **And that's the problem with static methods.** This Httpful library seems not to be a good choice if you want to write unit tests.

I see two options:

1. use a different, more test-friendly library, like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)
2. if that's not possible, write a thin wrapper, like this:

   ```
   class HttpfulClient
   {
       public function createGetRequest($url)
       {
           return \Httpful\Request::get($url);
       }
   }
   ```

   then pass an instance of this to the ApiClient constructor and mock it in your tests.

Comment: I switched over to using Guzzle, since it allows me to queue up mock responses. Then I can optionally pass the mocked Guzzle client into my API client via its constructor. Seems to be working well so far!